# HttpClient in while loop only executed once

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call HttpClient request inside for loop as follows. It needs to do multiple consecutive calls to third party rest api.
But it only gives me fist service call result while loop exit before getting result from rest of the service call.

```
 private void Search()
            {
                try
                {
                    var i = 1;
                    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        while (i < 5)
                        {
                            string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + i;
                            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                            string jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                            Console.WriteLine(jsonResult.ToString());
                         i++;                     
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

When I run with debug points the program gives me all the result. But when I run it without debug points it gives me only the first result.

I tried this with using async, await methods too. It also gives me same result.

As I feel Program needs to wait until the async call returns data.

Please help me to solve this.

EDIT - async way

```
private async Task<string> SearchNew()
        {
            try
            {
                var i = 1;
                var res = string.Empty;
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    while (i < 5)
                    {


                        string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + i;
                        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                        string jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        res = res + jsonResult + " --- ";
                        i++;
                    }

                }

                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Both are giving same result.

Comment: You really shouldn't be creating a new HttpClient on each loop.

Comment: And you should learn how to use async/await, using `.Result` is dangerous.

Comment: Apart from that, this code should work fine (assuming you only want it to loop 4 times)

Comment: You only need one HttpClient outside the while loop.  You only need a new response for each loop  inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the question based on your replies. I am calling google place API.It takes considerable time to return data.

Comment: So you just want to make multiple calls at the same time?

Comment: Your `i++;` is outside the while-loop, so I expect the loop to run **forever**.

Comment: Yes. I need make multiple service calls at the same time and get data.

Comment: @PeterB sorry about it. It's a typo error.I edited it.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few things here that you should be doing. First, move the `HttpClient` creation outside of your method and make it static. You only need one of them and having multiple can be really bad for stability ([see here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)):

```
private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
```

Next, extract the calls to the `HttpClient` into a single method, something simple like this:

```
//Please choose a better name than this
private async Task<string> GetData(string url)
{
    var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And finally, you create a list of tasks and wait for them all to complete asynchronously using [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-2.2):

```
private async Task<string[]> SearchAsync()
{
    var i = 1;

    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    //Create the tasks
    while (i < 5)
    {
        string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + i;
        tasks.Add(GetData(url));
        i++;
    }

    //Wait for the tasks to complete and return
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

And to call this method:

```
var results = await SearchAsync();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```